# Quickblox android audio/video chat crash

Tags: java, android, quickblox

Android application crashes while two users trying to audio/video calling eachother at the same time.

Note: This issue can reproduce almost all the time

Please anyone help me find the scenarios in which the following exception can happen.

```
 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-4432
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
            at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(HashMap.java:806)
            at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(HashMap.java:833)
            at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCSession$1.run(QBRTCSession.java:223)
            at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.LooperExecutor.execute(LooperExecutor.java:132)
            at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCSession.closeSession(QBRTCSession.java:209)
            at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCSession.closeSessionIfNeeded(QBRTCSession.java:187)
            at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCSession.access$600(QBRTCSession.java:42)
            at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.QBRTCSession$16.run(QBRTCSession.java:988)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
            at com.quickblox.videochat.webrtc.LooperExecutor.run(LooperExecutor.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on calling device when opponent hungs up, and after some research, I found out that at the moment listeners are notified about hung up, one of the listeners got deleted.

To avoid this you need to finish Call activity in `onSessionClosed` method.